# GC.GetTotalMemory minimal resolution

Tags: c#, memory

In unity (C#), I'm trying to find how much an impact a certain class or even a line of code have on the memory. 
I tried using GC.GetTotalMemory (with Gc.Collect right before), but it seems that the smallest gap between measurements is 4096 bytes.

Is there a way to get smaller 'chunks'?

I tried using `Process` class, but all memory properties return 0 (for unknown reason)

Comment: As the docs mention, `GC.GetTotalMemory` is only an *approximation* of how much memory is accessible. Just use a memory profiler. You're dealing with a managed application - the kind of memory allocation granularity you're asking for simply doesn't make sense. There's a lot of things going in background, you're in a multi-threaded application. There's also memory associated with loading the type (or assembly) itself... it's pretty much impossible to do any tests in isolation in an enviroment like this. The question is, why do you care?

Comment: I'm building a class that is being used tens of thousands of times, so each small addition to it has a lot of impact down the road. So I guess my only way is to make it 10000 times and then see the difference. :/
@cyberj0g - Visual studio tool doesn't seem to be able to attach to unity

Comment: That's usually the only approach that really makes sense. Whatever you're trying to measure, do it as close to real-world conditions as practical. It's not like it's *hard* to make thousands of instances of the same class :) Although do make sure you avoid some common pitfals that could skew your results - for example, using interned strings when in a real usage, each class would have its own instance of a string.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use memory profiler, you won't get much insight with your own code. For example, Visual Studio's built-in [Memory Usage tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/02/diagnosing-memory-issues-with-the-new-memory-usage-tool-in-visual-studio.aspx) can do the job nicely.